# Android app should close directly from any Activity

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to close the Android app by checking some condition which will be running in a while loop in **MainActivity**. It is closing completely when it is in the **MainActivity** but not in any **other Activity**. It is just closing the **current Activity** and start running the **MainActivity** but I want the close the app completely. The logics I have tried to close the app are

```
Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());


System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow();
```

Both the logics above works fine only if it is in **MainActivity**. Please help me out how can I close the app from any activity.

Comment: use finishAffinity();

Comment: @Firu using finishAffinity() is continuing the task where it has stopped before if I open it in recent apps. Is it possible to run from starting?

Comment: I don't think it is possible if you want to restart your app programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `finishAffinity();` which accroding to Activity documentation,

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.

Comment: Thanks for your approach, finishAffinity() is closing the app fine but I can open the app in recent apps and continue the task from where it has stopped before. Is there any possibility to kill all the running activities and run the app from starting.

Comment: I believe you're looking for `finishAndRemoveTask();`? Please try it and let me know